# No images displayed on the page after querying the database PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first post on stackoverflow after following posts for a very long time.
My problem is, I have a function that is supposed to retrieve data from a table (models) and display a name, location and an image to one of the pages. Everything is working but the images don't get displayed. Please look at my code and tell me what I should change to get these images to display. I'm using twitter bootstrap for styling.
My directory is: localhost/mainsite/admin/uploads

I've checked everything related to this post and tried it out but they didn't solve my problem. So please help.

```html
function view_models() {
 
 global $dbc;
 
 $q = "SELECT * FROM models";
 $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
 
 while ($row = @ mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
  
  $id = $row['model_id'];
  $mn = $row['model_name'];
  $ln = $row['location'];
  $img = $row['image1'];
  
  echo "
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-lg-3'>
         
     <h3>$mn</h3>
     <a href='details.php?id=$id'>         
     <img src='admin/uploads/$img' class='img-thumbnail' />
     <p>$ln</p>
          
    
    </div>";
  
 
  
  
 }

}
```

Comment: if you echo `$img` outside of the echo above, what does it contain? Try `var_dump($img);`

Comment: Also, maybe you should check if the image exists at that location. Perhaps you need to add a `/` before the URL?

Comment: It outputs each name of the image plus its extension and the number of characters as they appear in the database e.g string(8) "pose.jpg"

Comment: you mixed php and the html with `'&"` check that?

Comment: `echo "<div class=''>".$x."</div>` or `echo '<div class="">'.$x.'</div>'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.,
I have changed the echo statement because you did a error, that was misplaced `'`&`"`

```
echo "<div class='col-xs-6 col-lg-3'>
      <h3>".$mn."</h3>
        <a href='details.php?id=".$id."'>                                   
          <img src='admin/uploads/".$img."' class='img-thumbnail' />
          <p>".$ln."</p>
        </a>                                    
    </div>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Unfortunately I cant vote up coz I don't have enough points to do so. You've helped me a lot though coz I wasn't seeing what I did wrong.